# How to use if inline helper in glimmer application

Tags: glimmer.js

when i tried to use if helper in glimmer application.It gives me an error like `Uncaught Error: Compile Error: if is not a helper`

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: Starting with v0.8.0 there is an inline `if`.

The version of Glimmerjs you are using does not have an inline `if` helper, you can either implement it yourself or upgrade your Glimmerjs project to v0.8.0.

To create the helper, run `ember g glimmer-helper if`, and then edit the file with the following:

```
// src/ui/components/if/helper.ts

export default function helper([cond, truthy, falsy]) {
  return cond ? truthy : falsy;
}
```

To update, I suggest using [ember-cli-update](https://github.com/kellyselden/ember-cli-update#installation). On top of upgrading your dependencies, you will also have to update your components to the new `<Capital>` syntax.